# WatchKit - Cannot transferFile in background "Watch App is not installed"

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I am attempting to transfer an image file in the background using the WCSession method transferFile.

I am pulling photos from PHPhotoLibrary, (local photos). Then storing them in the caches directory to be sent via the transfer. The images are written successfully and saved to the location.

```
let manager = PhotoManager()
    manager.requestPhotos { (error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let fileURLs = manager.findFilesInCache() {
                for file in fileURLs {
                    print(file)
                    self.session.transferFile(file, metadata: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Watch's side:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        // Perform any final initialization of your application.

        //Initialize the WCSession
        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            WCSession.defaultSession().delegate = self;
            WCSession.defaultSession().activateSession()

        }
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveFile file: WCSessionFile) {
        print (file.fileURL)
    }
```

However, I continuously get this error from didFinishFileTransfer...

```
"Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7006 \"Watch app is not installed.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Install the Watch app., NSLocalizedDescription=Watch app is not installed.}"
```

I have tried everything. Reinstalling the app, rebuilding the project. Reopening Xcode. Reconnecting my watch.... I'm going to try restating my computer.

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: Did you go into the Watch app on the phone and add your app?

Comment: Hmm, through Xcode it installs just fine. But installing it through the Watch app it fails to install.

Comment: Does the app show up on the watch?

Comment: only if its built and run in xcode. I cannot get "Show App on Apple Watch" to install the app. it Installs about half way then crashes. @milesper

Comment: You should fix the watch app installation issue since that is a reasonable cause for this question's error message. You can examine the watch's console log for more details, which you can find in Xcode -> Window -> Devices.